# Get user from sharepoint group and redirect

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-object-model

My requirement is when someone login to site and if he belong to 'owner' group it need to redirect immediately to specific site and if he belong to member group then need to navigate/redirect to same specified site other page.

Comment: This requirement seems very easy to fulfill. Which problem are you facing exactly? What did you tried?

Comment: user login the local system means windows login and enter the sharepoint url open the he related page means not home page other page means page 1 i created new page in site name: page1 and admin will login that system home page will open. how to do please explain this is sharepoint site 2010 functionality

Comment: this is the task Steve please explain we need urzent

Comment: You did not answer to my question. And please, do not tells it is urgent. Good questions will have chances to get quickly good answer. Your question is not properly written.

Comment: i worte javascript, based on the login user home page will open not open page1

Comment: i want starting to end flow

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution could be to use `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`. What it does is that it adds whatever is inside the control only if the specified access is fulfilled by the user.

So what you can do is that set the permissioning of the control to full control and include a simple redirect JavaScript. And just after that, outside the control, add a redirect script to other control. Something like below:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" Permissions="ManageWeb" PermissionContext="CurrentSite">  
    <script type='text/javascript'>javascript to redirect owners</script>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl> 
<script type='text/javascript'>javascript to redirect readers</script>
```

So if the user is an owner, the owner redirect sscript will be present on the page and if not then it will redirect to the reader's page.

Comment: where i can add this script @saksham

Comment: just search google "Javascript to redirect" would give you tons of solutions. @PrasanthNellore

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in SP2010, I assume we use server side C# code instead of CSOM, which is not matured yet in SP2010.

1. create a static helper method like:

   public static bool IsInGroup(this SPUser user, SPGroup group)
         {
           return user.Groups.Cast()
             .Any(g => g.ID == group.ID);
         }
      }
2. verify in your code if the user belongs to certain group

   SPUser user;
   SPGroup group;
   bool belongToGroup = user.InGroup(group);
3. use SPUtility.Redirect to redirect the user to any page you need.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: please let me explain some more functionality